# Why isn't the JWST mirror bigger?

Tags: payload, space-telescope, payload-deployment, james-webb-telescope

What's behind the choice of not designing the largest possible folding mirror for the James Webb space telescope, since something like a 13m diameter mirror could also fit in Ariane's fairing?

[image: folding mirror]

Comment: I suspect that the determining factor in the overall size of the Webb is not how big a mirror they could send up, but how large a sun-shield they could send up.  I haven't been able to corroborate this, though.

Comment: A more complex folding mechanism is... more complex. As it is, the folding mechanism is one of the high-risk items with lots of mechanical actions that have to happen just right to get the telescope to work. Using 3x more folding mechanisms reduces reliability by a large factor.

Comment: Mass, cost, complexity, pick any 3.